# Common part in associations rails, should I use merge?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

**Update 2**

```
Cama::PostType.first.posts.joins(:custom_field_values)
.where("cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? AND 
cama_custom_fields_relationships.value LIKE ?","localization", 
"%Paris%").merge(Cama::PostType.first.posts.joins(:custom_field_values)
.where("cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? AND cama_custom_fields_relationships.value = ?","type-localization", "2"))
```

Why this merge doesn't work ?

It returns me same result when executed seperately... Merge should work as intersection so common part should be result. I dont get it

**Update**

I will try to ask in more conceptual way.

I have model B that have slug:text, value:text, belongs_to: Model A

I have model A that have name:string, has_many: Model B

@posts_one = I search for model B where slug="something", value = "city"

@posts_two = I search for model B where slug="mood", value="good"

I have 2 results based on diffrent parameters. Both belongs_to: model A

Now I want to return only the common `belongs_to`. 
so if

@posts_one will return me 20 results with model_a_ids

@posts_two will return me 20 results with model_a_ids

I want to return only common model_a_ids of those 2 queries and right away to find posts. I try to make it in one query but dont know if its possible

**Oryginal post**

I use Camaleon CMS and I try to create filters based on additional "custom fields". I think to answer this question you dont have to know this cms.

I want to find common part of 2 queries or make it in one query(that would be the best)

I have

```
@posts = Cama::PostType.first.posts.includes(:custom_field_values)
@param_localization = "Paris"
@param_type_localization = "House"


@posts_one = @posts.merge(CamaleonCms::CustomFieldsRelationship.
where("cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? AND 
LOWER(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value) LIKE ?", "localization",
"%#{@param_localization}%"))

puts @posts_one.count => 2


@posts_two = @posts.merge(CamaleonCms::CustomFieldsRelationship.where(custom_field_slug:
"type-localization", value: @param_type_localization))

puts @posts_two.count => 2
```

Question is how can I merge it together or make it one query ? When I made it in one `where clause` it returns me 0 results since I need to find 2 diffrent custom fields relationships that has diffrent values and slugs but it have relations to posts throught :custom_fields_values, so I have to make 2 queries I guess(like I did). First I find customFieldRelationship with `slug = localization` and second with `slug = type_localization` and then I need to find `common part`

I tried to `@result = @posts_one.merge(@posts_two)` but I got no result then. I thought it will return me "**common part**" of association which means **2 results**

How can I combine it to find me posts that fullfil both queries ?

Let me know if I explained my problem not well enought.

Comment: Let me know if I explained my problem not well enought.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to combine it in SQL: (untested)

```
@posts_combined = @posts.merge(CamaleonCms::CustomFieldsRelationship.
where("(cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? 
  OR cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = 'type-localization') 
  AND LOWER(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value) LIKE ? ", "localization", 
  "%#{@param_localization}%"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It doesnt have @param_type_localization as value for sług type-localization. I need to find posts that fullfill both queries. Post needs to have localization Paris and Type localization house. Im searching for seperate relationships but want to return only common ids/posts